# extjs store fail

Tags: extjs, extjs4, store, extjs4.1

ExtJS Model fields have mapping option.

```
fields: [
        {name: 'brandId', mapping:'brand.id',   type: 'int'},
        {name: 'brandName', mapping:'brand.name', type: 'string'},
```

The problem is: if the response from server does not contain some field(brand field in my example) and mapping from inner fields is defined, Ext Store silently fails to load any records.

Does anybody have problems with this? Is it some kind of a bug?

**UPDATE**
To make it clear: suppose I have ten fields in my model. Response from server has nine fields, one is missing. If there is no nested mapping for this field (mapping:'x.y.z') everything is OK - store loads record, the field is empty. But if this field has to be loaded from some nested field and has mapping option - store fails to load ANYTHING.

**UPDATE 2**
I have found the code, that causes problems. The fact is: when Ext tries to load some field from Json it performs a check like this

```
(source["id"] === undefined) ? __field0.defaultValue : source["id"]
```

But when field has mapping option(mapping 'brand.id') Reader does it this way

```
(source.brand.id === undefined) ? __field20.defaultValue : source.brand.id
```

which causes error if source has no brand field.

In case you have same problems as I: you can fix it by overloading *Ext.data.reader.Json*'s method  *createFieldAccessExpression*

Comment: What other behaviour would you expect if the store fails to find it's record in the response? I mean, what is your issue with this behaviour?

Comment: Well, the record comes from server, it just doesn't have "brand" field. If a record misses some field and there is no mapping, everything is OK, the store loads record, the field is empty

Comment: "(brand field in my example)" You don't have a brand field shown here. You have a brandId and brandName. Please clarify.

Comment: There is no brand field in model, but there should be brand field in server response "brand":{"id":"1","name":"Hyundai"} Am I clear?

Comment: "The Store silently fails to load any records" is just because it can not determine what the actual data of `brand` in the server (`brand` is not received in the response, so how can the store get brand.id and brand.name). And if `brand` is not determined, how the store know whether this field has been changed comparing to actual data on server in order to update. So event handling in this case will be impossible.

Comment: I do not agree. When no mapping is defined on the field and the field is missing in server response, store still loads records perfectly. How can you explain this?

Answer (score 2):

I agree that Ext should only fail to load that field, not the entire record.  One option that isn't great, but should work, is instead use a `mapping` function:

```
{
    name: 'brandId',
    mapping: function(data, record) {
        return data.brand && data.brand.id;
    }
}
```

I could have the arguments wrong (I figured out that this feature existed by looking at the source code), so maybe put a breakpoint in there to see what's available if it doesn't work like this.

Comment: FYI this was a design decision, data reading can be pretty slow, so having to have a try catch block in the case where some "complex" json expression is used wouldn't be ideal.

Comment: Maybe Ext could do kinda what I did in this reply, which is use "&&"-separated dot paths, so that if it didn't exist you'd get `false`

Comment: Good idea, BigSean. But I went with "try ... catch..." block.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misinterpret `mapping` and `nesting` paradigms: these are not interchangeable.
If you define nesting in your data, the result MUST have the corresponding field.

Comment: Yeah, it turns out it works this way, but documentation says nothing about it and I think this is incorrect behaviour.